# C language bresenhamLine Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, line

I am confused about what could be the problem in this algorithm:

With these parameters:

```
ine temp = {(Vector){10, 150}, (Vector){120, 40}, polygon->color}; 
drawaLine(monitor, &temp);
```

However, when I change the coordinates to `120, 20` it fails:

```
Line temp = {(Vector){10, 150}, (Vector){120, 20}, polygon->color}; 
drawaLine(monitor, &temp);
```

My code is:

```
    int changed = 0;
    int x = line->start.x;
    int y = line->start.y;
    int dx = (line->end.x - line->start.x);
    int dy = (line->end.y - line->start.y);

    dx = (dx < 0) ? -dx : dx;
    dy = (dy < 0) ? -dy : dy;

    int signx;
    int signy;

    if ((line->end.x - line->start.x) == 0) {

            signx = 0;
    } else {
        int tempsignx = (line->end.x - line->start.x);
        signx = (tempsignx < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    if ((line->end.y - line->start.y) == 0) {

        signy = 0;
    } else {
            int tempsingy = (line->end.y - line->start.y);
        signy = (tempsingy < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    }


    //swap values
    if (dy > dx) {
        int temp = dy;
        dy = dx;
        dx = temp;
        changed = 1;        //changed = true
    }

    int e = 2 * dy - dx;

    for (int i = 1; i <= dx; i++) {


        Vector temp = {x, y};

        drawPixel(monitor,  temp, line->color);
        while (e >= 0) {

                  if (changed) {

                      x = x + signx;
                    } else {

                      y = y + signy;
                      e = e - 2 * dx;
                }
       }
        if (changed) {

          y += signy;
         } else {

          x += signx;
          e = e + 2 * dy;
        }


      Vector x2y2 = {line->end.x, line->end.y};
      drawPixel(monitor, x2y2, line->color);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't help you without knowing what `Vector` is, how it's declared, whether it is `typedef`'ed, etc.. I should be able to compile what you post an at least read the warnings and errors -- without having to write code for you.

Comment: while(e>=0) change to if(e>=0)

Comment: Please indent properly so the code is easily readable.